# Как совершать действия по нажатиям на кнопки? Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

Создал окно программы с пунктами и подпунктами. Каким образом можно "оживить" Кнопки? Например как сделать чтобы по нажатию на "Файл">"Выход" программа закрывалась? Я в этом очень плохо что понимаю, скорее даже ничего...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#define IDM_SHOW      1001
#define IDM_ERASE     1002
#define IDM_EXIT      1003
#pragma comment(lib, "ComCtl32.lib")

TCHAR czClassName[] = L"myClass";
TCHAR czFormName[] = L"Это мое окно";
HWND hwndA;
const WCHAR wString[] = L"Hello";
#define countof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*(a)))
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hDeviceContext;
    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    RECT rectPlace;
    HFONT hFont;
    static char text[2] = { ' ','\0' };
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == 0 && lParam == 0) {    // If a menu item has been selected
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
            case IDM_SHOW:
                MessageBox(NULL,
                    L"Покулитый Руслан",
                    L"121-18ск-1", MB_ICONASTERISK | MB_OK);
                break;


            case IDM_ERASE:
                ::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);

                    break;


            case IDM_EXIT:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
            break;

    default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam); break;
        }
    }
}

ATOM myRegistryClass(HINSTANCE hInst, int cmdMode)
{
    WNDCLASS cw;

    cw.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    cw.cbClsExtra = 0;
    cw.cbWndExtra = 0;
    cw.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2);
    cw.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    cw.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    cw.hInstance = hInst;
    cw.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    cw.lpszClassName = czClassName;
    cw.lpszMenuName = NULL;

    RegisterClass(&cw);

    return 0;
}


BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInst, int Mode)
{


    hwndA = CreateWindow(
        czClassName,
        czFormName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwndA, Mode);
    UpdateWindow(hwndA);

    return TRUE;
}


/*Главная функция*/
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR IpszCmdParam, int cmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    myRegistryClass(hInst, cmdShow);
    InitInstance(hInst, cmdShow);

    InitCommonControls();

    /*Создание строки состояния*/
    HWND hStatusWindow = CreateStatusWindow(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, L"", hwndA, 5000);

    HMENU hmenu1;
    hmenu1 = CreateMenu();

    HMENU hMainMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hPopMenuFile = CreatePopupMenu();
    HMENU hPopMenuPravka = CreatePopupMenu();
    HMENU hPopMenuPomosh = CreatePopupMenu();

    AppendMenu(hMainMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hPopMenuFile, L"Файл");
    AppendMenu(hMainMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hPopMenuPravka, L"Правка");
    AppendMenu(hMainMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hPopMenuPomosh, L"Помощь");


    AppendMenu(hPopMenuFile, MF_STRING, 1001, L"Показать");
    AppendMenu(hPopMenuFile, MF_STRING, 1003, L"Выход");
    AppendMenu(hPopMenuPravka, MF_STRING, 1002, L"Стереть");

    SetMenu(hwndA, hMainMenu);
    SetMenu(hwndA, hPopMenuFile);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: обрабатывать сообщения

Comment: Руслан, вам обязательно чистый винапи использовать? для создания графического интерфейса это не самый оптимальный способ. Даже тот же mfc позволяет автоматизировать кучу винапи-рутины и "накликать" интерфейс мышкой

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, у вас ошибка в AppendMenu - две разные команды имеют один и тот же идентификатор 1001.

Во-вторых, меню, акселераторы, кнопки, и прочие экранные элементы при активации генерируют сообщение WM_COMMAND. Для обработки команд меню в вашу оконную процедуру надо добавить примерно такой код (я добавил символьные идентификаторы для ваших команд):

```
#define IDM_SHOW      1001
#define IDM_ERASE     1002
#define IDM_EXIT      1003

switch (message) {
  . . .
  case WM_COMMAND:
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == 0 && lParam == 0) {    // If a menu item has been selected
      switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDM_SHOW:
          . . .
          break;

        case IDM_ERASE:
          . . .
          break;

        case IDM_EXIT:
          ::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
          break;
      }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. У меня очередной вопрос(понимаю что достал уже, но я по другому не знаю как быть, надеюсь на вашу помощь). Как теперь удалить при  открытии "файл">>"Показать"( где появляется выведенная строка в отдельном окне ), через "Правка">>"стереть". Т.е. после открытия данной строки, она должна удалятся по нажатию на "Правка">>"стереть" , а если данная строка не была вызвана , то и кнопка "правка" не должна быть активна? Надеюсь на ваш ответ. Код я изменил в самом вопросе на тот который использую в данный момент

Comment: @Руслан, не понял что вы хотите сделать... Изменить меню, чтобы после открытия файла добавить/удалить какие-то пункты или что-то другое? Может, вы лучше новый вопрос зададите, ну и сформулируете его попонятнее?

Comment: Вот что требуется "В пункте меню Правка содержит следующий подпункт: Стереть, при выборе которого, загруженная строка выгружается, а если она не была загружена, этот пункт меню не является доступным", эта строка загружается из "Файл">>"Показать".

Comment: @Руслан, сделать элемент меню недоступным/серым (и наоборот) можно функцией `EnableMenuItem`.

Comment: А как удалить вызванную строку через другой пункт в Меню стандартного окна?

Comment: @Руслан, вообще непонятно что вы хотите сделать. Что такое "вызванная строка"? Что это за строка и откуда (и куда) она вызвана? Текст вашей программы никаких намеков на это не дает. Вы поймите, что другие люди не в курсе ваших идей, и им нужно подробно и понятно объяснять. Давайте лучше вы это нормально сформулируете и откроете новый вопрос. Комментарии это не чат.