# Удаление окна строки

Tags: c++, winapi, api

Здраствуйте, есть вот такое вот задание

Создать 32-х разрядное приложение – стандартное окно с использованием следующих ресурсов:
* Строки 
* Меню 
Меню стандартного окна состоит из следующих пунктов: Файл, Правка и Помощь. В пункте меню Файл содержатся следующий подпункт: Показать и Выход При выборе подпункта Показать, в окне появляется строка, а при выборе Выход – программа завершает свою работу. В пункте меню Правка содержит следующий подпункт: Стереть, при выборе которого, загруженная строка выгружается, а если она не была загружена, этот пункт меню не является доступным. И наконец, в пункте меню Помощь не содержится никаких подпунктов.

Есть готовый код

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#define IDM_SHOW      1001
#define IDM_ERASE     1002
#define IDM_EXIT      1003
#pragma comment(lib, "ComCtl32.lib")

TCHAR czClassName[] = L"myClass";
TCHAR czFormName[] = L"Это мое окно";
HWND hwndA;
const WCHAR wString[] = L"Hello";
#define countof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*(a)))
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hDeviceContext;
    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    RECT rectPlace;
    HFONT hFont;
    static char text[2] = { ' ','\0' };
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == 0 && lParam == 0) {    // If a menu item has been selected
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
            case IDM_SHOW:
                MessageBox(NULL,
                    L"Покулитый Руслан",
                    L"121-18ск-1", MB_ICONASTERISK | MB_OK);
                break;


            case IDM_ERASE:
                EnableMenuItem;


                break;


            case IDM_EXIT:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
            break;

    default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam); break;
        }
    }
}

ATOM myRegistryClass(HINSTANCE hInst, int cmdMode)
{
    WNDCLASS cw;

    cw.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    cw.cbClsExtra = 0;
    cw.cbWndExtra = 0;
    cw.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2);
    cw.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    cw.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    cw.hInstance = hInst;
    cw.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    cw.lpszClassName = czClassName;
    cw.lpszMenuName = NULL;

    RegisterClass(&cw);

    return 0;
}


BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInst, int Mode)
{


    hwndA = CreateWindow(
        czClassName,
        czFormName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwndA, Mode);
    UpdateWindow(hwndA);

    return TRUE;
}


/*Главная функция*/
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR IpszCmdParam, int cmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    myRegistryClass(hInst, cmdShow);
    InitInstance(hInst, cmdShow);

    InitCommonControls();

    /*Создание строки состояния*/
    HWND hStatusWindow = CreateStatusWindow(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, L"", hwndA, 5000);

    HMENU hmenu1;
    hmenu1 = CreateMenu();

    HMENU hMainMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hPopMenuFile = CreatePopupMenu();
    HMENU hPopMenuPravka = CreatePopupMenu();
    HMENU hPopMenuPomosh = CreatePopupMenu();

    AppendMenu(hMainMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hPopMenuFile, L"Файл");
    AppendMenu(hMainMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hPopMenuPravka, L"Правка");
    AppendMenu(hMainMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hPopMenuPomosh, L"Помощь");


    AppendMenu(hPopMenuFile, MF_STRING, 1001, L"Показать");
    AppendMenu(hPopMenuFile, MF_STRING, 1003, L"Выход");
    AppendMenu(hPopMenuPravka, MF_STRING, 1002, L"Стереть");

    SetMenu(hwndA, hMainMenu);
    SetMenu(hwndA, hPopMenuFile);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите как можно реализовать вот этот пункт в задании

"В пункте меню Правка содержит следующий подпункт: Стереть, при выборе которого, загруженная строка выгружается, а если она не была загружена, этот пункт меню не является доступным."

Я мало что в этом понимаю, поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Мне кажется это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/903374/17974 похоже на правду. В обработчик - добавить желаемое поведение. Или не понятно как обработчик писать?

Comment: Да, это оно. Тот кто помогал ответить попросил чтобы я задал новый вопрос и сформулировал его более понятно. Я скажу честно, я понимаю в этом практически ничего и обработчик так же для меня большая загадка... Как я понимаю выгружается-значит просто удалить это окно, я не знаю, все требуемые условия для задания предоставлены в описании. Мне бы просто чтобы МеседжБокс который появляется, удалялся через кнопку сделать...

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что вам необходимо сделать, это разобраться как построена программа для Windows, тогда большинство вопросов сразу отпадет. Есть такая классическая книжка: Петцольд Ч. Программирование для Windows 95. Набираете в Яндексе и сразу получаете кучу ссылок для скачивания. Вам там нужны: глава 2 - общая информация о структуре Windows программы; глава 3 - вывод текста в окно программы; глава 10 - работа с меню.

Что касается конкретно меню "Стереть". Сначала этот пункт создается неактивным. По команде "Показать" отрисовываете текст и вызываете `EnableMenuItem` чтобы сделать пункт "Стереть" активным. При вызове "Стереть" очищаете окно и вызываете `EnableMenuItem` чтобы сделать пункт "Стереть" опять неактивным.